# What is the best way to consume aws-iot services through MQTT protocol on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mono, mqtt, aws-iot

I googled around this topic and found I need to use M2MQTT(https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/m2mqtt-and-amazon-aws-iot/) from this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=759987
From this blog https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/m2mqtt-and-amazon-aws-iot/ I understand that M2MQTT is not capable updating the AWS Shadows(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-thing-shadows.html), which is heart of my iot application, So this is not suitable for us. Is there any alternative to integrate AWS IOT through MQTT in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 0):

M2MQTT does support updating the shadows - this is simply done with standard MQTT messages so doesn't need particular client support. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/using-device-shadows.html for details.

(The link you give just says this wasn't included in the linked sample app, not that it wasn't supported).